# python data frame key error on calling columns by index

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

```
subset = df[['country', 'continent', 'year']]
subset.head()
```

This code is working fine but

```
subset = df[[1, 2, 3]]
```

is giving me an error

```
KeyError: '[1 2 3] not in index'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the columns by index try:

```
subset = df.iloc[:,[1, 2, 3]]
```

or use `df.columns` and pass the list same way above.

```
subset = df[df.columns[[1, 2, 3]]]
```

Assuming your column `country` is at `1` column index.